# Extended Kalman Filter prediction update time

Tags: matlab, object-detection, prediction, kalman-filter, radar-chart

enter code hereI have implemented a Kalman filter for tracking moving objects using radar data. I have designed and generated data using the Matlab ADAS toolbox. After generating I have fed the data to the code which I have written in Matlab ( Filter - EKF, Gating - Euclidean Distance, Data Association- Probabilistic data association, initialization of tracks based on distance). So, now after executing, I have noticed that the prediction is not updating with respect to the detections. Its a bit slow compared to the detection inputs. Here an image below. So, the yellow one is the Kalman prediction and the red are the detections. So, because of late predictions and detections getting fast, the gating is coming out to be with zero detections to input to the PDA block. Due to this, the prediction is throwing NAN( Not a Number). And in order to solve this, the filter should fastly predict so we get enough detections for future predictions.
So, my question is how to do the predictions faulty associated with the detections.

```
This is the code 

This is the predict function
function [TrackList, Evaluate] = predict( Evaluate,scans,TrackList,Par,associated_data,Track_no)
persistent prev
if (~isempty(TrackList{Track_no}))
    if(scans>1)
     TrackList{Track_no}.X = (TrackList{Track_no}.State_trans_mtx_F)*(TrackList{Track_no}.X);
    else
        prev = 0;
    end

     Evaluate.X(scans,:) = TrackList{Track_no}.X;


     TrackList{Track_no}.range_A = sqrt((TrackList{Track_no}.X(1)^2)+(TrackList{Track_no}.X(4)^2));
     TrackList{Track_no}.bearing_A = atan2(TrackList{Track_no}.X(4),TrackList{Track_no}.X(1));
     TrackList{Track_no}.yhat = [TrackList{Track_no}.range_A  TrackList{Track_no}.X(2) TrackList{Track_no}.X(3) TrackList{Track_no}.bearing_A  TrackList{Track_no}.X(5) TrackList{Track_no}.X(6)];

     Evaluate.Yhat(scans,:) = TrackList{Track_no}.yhat;

     TrackList{Track_no}.meas_trans_mtx_H = [cos(TrackList{Track_no}.bearing_A) 0 0 sin(TrackList{Track_no}.bearing_A) 0 0 ;
                         0 1 0 0 0 0;
                         0 0 1 0 0 0;
                        -sin(TrackList{Track_no}.bearing_A)/TrackList{Track_no}.range_A 0 0 cos(TrackList{Track_no}.bearing_A)/TrackList{Track_no}.range_A 0 0;
                         0 0 0 0 1 0;
                         0 0 0 0 0 1];

    Evaluate.meas_trans_mtx_H(scans).m = TrackList{Track_no}.meas_trans_mtx_H;

    TrackList{Track_no}.Corr_mtx_error_P = (TrackList{Track_no}.State_trans_mtx_F)*(TrackList{Track_no}.Corr_mtx_error_P)*((TrackList{Track_no}.State_trans_mtx_F)') + Par.process_cov_Q;

    Evaluate.Corr_mtx_error_P(scans).m = TrackList{Track_no}.Corr_mtx_error_P ;


    TrackList{Track_no}.innovation_cov_S = (TrackList{Track_no}.meas_trans_mtx_H)*(TrackList{Track_no}.Corr_mtx_error_P)*(TrackList{Track_no}.meas_trans_mtx_H') + (TrackList{Track_no}.meas_cov_R);

    Evaluate.innovation_cov_S(scans).m = TrackList{Track_no}.innovation_cov_S;

    associated_meas.index = 1;
    associated_meas.meas = [];
    for k = 1:size(associated_data,1)
        [associated_meas,dis] = gating(associated_meas,associated_data(k,:),TrackList{Track_no}.yhat,Par.gateLevel,TrackList{Track_no}.innovation_cov_S); 
        Evaluate.dis(k + prev) = dis;
    end
    prev = k + prev;
    Evaluate.associated_data(scans).meas = associated_meas;
    TrackList{Track_no}.associated_meas.index = associated_meas.index;
    TrackList{Track_no}.associated_meas.meas = associated_meas.meas;
    figure(1);
    polarplot(TrackList{Track_no}.yhat(4),TrackList{Track_no}.yhat(1),'o');

end
end

This is the update function
function [TrackList,Evaluate] = update(Evaluate,TrackList,Par,Track_no,scans)
    % for i = 1:size(TrackList,2)
if (~isempty(TrackList{Track_no})) %#ok<*ALIGN>
    TrackList{Track_no}.Kalman_gain = (TrackList{Track_no}.Corr_mtx_error_P)*(TrackList{Track_no}.meas_trans_mtx_H')/(TrackList{Track_no}.innovation_cov_S);

    Evaluate.Kalman_gain(scans).m = TrackList{Track_no}.Kalman_gain ;

    % PDA
    [innov,TrackList] = PDA(TrackList,Track_no);
    Evaluate.innov(scans).m = innov;
    % Update the state and covariance estimates
    TrackList{Track_no}.Kalman_gain(3,3) = 0;
    TrackList{Track_no}.Kalman_gain(6,6) = 0;

    TrackList{Track_no}.X = TrackList{Track_no}.X + (TrackList{Track_no}.Kalman_gain)*innov';
    Evaluate.updated_X(scans,:) = TrackList{Track_no}.X;
    %% 
    TrackList{Track_no}.Vx_save(TrackList{Track_no}.count,1) = TrackList{Track_no}.X(2);
    TrackList{Track_no}.Vy_save(TrackList{Track_no}.count,1) = TrackList{Track_no}.X(5);
    % calculating acceleration from velocities

    if(TrackList{Track_no}.count>2)
        TrackList{Track_no}.X(3) =  (TrackList{Track_no}.Vx_save(TrackList{Track_no}.count,1) - TrackList{Track_no}.Vx_save(TrackList{Track_no}.count-1,1))/Par.dt;
        % Ax_save(count,1) = TrackList{i}.X(3); 
        TrackList{Track_no}.X(6) =  (TrackList{Track_no}.Vy_save(TrackList{Track_no}.count,1) - TrackList{Track_no}.Vy_save(TrackList{Track_no}.count-1,1))/Par.dt;
        % Ay_save(count,1)= TrackList{i}.X(6);
    end
    Evaluate.updated_X_acc(scans,:) = TrackList{Track_no}.X;
    TrackList{Track_no}.Kalman_out = TrackList{Track_no}.X;
    TrackList{Track_no}.count = TrackList{Track_no}.count + 1;           

  end
end

This is the track initialization
function [TrackList] = initialize(TrackList,clustered_data,Par,cluster_id,iterate,c11,c22)
if(iterate == 1)
    for id = 1:cluster_id
       TrackList = add_track(TrackList,clustered_data,Par,id,c11,c22);
    end
else
    for track_no = 1:size(TrackList,2)
        n = 0;
        for id = 1:cluster_id
         [t,r] = cart2pol(TrackList{track_no}.X(1),TrackList{track_no}.X(4));    
         dis = pdist2([r t],[clustered_data(id).meas{1,1} clustered_data(id).meas{1,4}]);
         if(dis < Par.gateLevel)
             TrackList{track_no}.associated_data = clustered_data(id).meas;
         end
         if(dis > Par.gateLevel+10)
             n = n+1;
             if(n == size(TrackList,2))
                 TrackList = add_track(TrackList,clustered_data,Par,id,c11,c22);
                 TrackList{track_no}.associated_data = clustered_data(id).meas;   
             end
         end
        end

    end
end
end


function TrackList = add_track(TrackList,clustered_data,Par,id,c11,c22)
            Track_id = size(TrackList,2) + 1;
            TrackList{Track_id}.meas.range = clustered_data(id).meas{1,1};
            TrackList{Track_id}.meas.bearing = clustered_data(id).meas{1,4};
            TrackList{Track_id}.meas.vx = clustered_data(id).meas{1,2};
            TrackList{Track_id}.meas.vy = clustered_data(id).meas{1,5};
            angle = clustered_data(id).meas{1,4};
            range = clustered_data(id).meas{1,1};
%             TrackList{Track_id}.meas_cov_R = [(Par.meas_std_range)^2*angle 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) 0 0 0;
%                   0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_vel)^2 (Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)*0 0 0 0;
%                   0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) 0*(Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)  (Par.meas_std_acc)^2 0 0 0;
%                   0 0 0  (Par.meas_std_bearing)^2*angle 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc);
%                   0 0 0 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_vel)^2 0*(Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)
%                   0 0 0 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) 0*(Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc) (Par.meas_std_acc)^2];

                Par.meas_std_dis_x = Par.meas_std_range*(cos(angle)^2) + (range^2)*(sin(angle)^2)*Par.meas_std_bearing;
                Par.meas_std_dis_y = Par.meas_std_range*(sin(angle)^2) + (range^2)*(cos(angle)^2)*Par.meas_std_bearing;

                TrackList{Track_id}.meas_cov_R = [Par.meas_std_dis_x  0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) 0 0 0;
                  0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_vel)^2 (Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)*0 0 0 0;
                  0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) 0*(Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)  (Par.meas_std_acc)^2 0 0 0;
                  0 0 0 Par.meas_std_dis_y 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc);
                  0 0 0 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_vel)^2 0*(Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)
                  0 0 0 0*(Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) 0*(Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc) (Par.meas_std_acc)^2];

%               TrackList{Track_id}.meas_cov_R = [(Par.meas_std_range)^2*angle (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) 0 0 0;
%                   (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_vel)^2 (Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)*0 0 0 0;
%                   (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) (Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)  (Par.meas_std_acc)^2 0 0 0;
%                   0 0 0  (Par.meas_std_bearing)^2*angle (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc);
%                   0 0 0 (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_vel) (Par.meas_std_vel)^2 (Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc)
%                   0 0 0 (Par.meas_std_dis)*(Par.meas_std_acc) (Par.meas_std_vel)*(Par.meas_std_acc) (Par.meas_std_acc)^2];
%               
          %TrackList{Track_id}.meas_cov_R = TrackList{Track_id}.meas_cov_R + 0.1*diag([1 0 1 1 0 1]);
          TrackList{Track_id}.X = [clustered_data(id).meas{1,1}*cos(clustered_data(id).meas{1,4});clustered_data(id).meas{1,2};0;clustered_data(id).meas{1,1}*sin((clustered_data(id).meas{1,4}));clustered_data(id).meas{1,5};0];
          % TrackList{Track_id}.X = [c11(id)+0.5;clustered_data(id).meas{1,2};0;c22(id)+0.5;clustered_data(id).meas{1,5};0];

          TrackList{Track_id}.Corr_mtx_error_P = zeros(6,6);
           TrackList{Track_id}.State_trans_mtx_F = [1 Par.dt 0.5*(Par.dt^2) 0 0 0;
                                         0 1 Par.dt 0 0 0;
                                         0 0 1 0 0 0;
                                         0 0 0 1 Par.dt 0.5*(Par.dt^2);
                                         0 0 0 0 1 Par.dt;
                                         0 0 0 0 0 1];
            TrackList{Track_id}.Vx_save = zeros(1,1);
            TrackList{Track_id}.Vy_save = zeros(1,1);
            TrackList{Track_id}.associated_data = clustered_data(id).meas;
            TrackList{Track_id}.count = 1;
            TrackList{Track_id}.death = 0;
            TrackList{Track_id}.range_A = 0;
            TrackList{Track_id}.bearing_A = 0;
            TrackList{Track_id}.yhat = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
            TrackList{Track_id}.meas_trans_mtx_H = zeros(6,6);    
            TrackList{Track_id}.Corr_mtx_error_P = zeros(6,6);
            TrackList{Track_id}.innovation_cov_S = zeros(6,6);
            TrackList{Track_id}.Kalman_gain = zeros(6,6);
            TrackList{Track_id}.Vx_save = [];
            TrackList{Track_id}.Vy_save = []; 
            TrackList{Track_id}.count  = 1;
                 Par.process_cov_Q = [((Par.sig_ax^2)*(Par.dt^4))/4 ((Par.sig_ax^2)*(Par.dt^3))/2 ((Par.dt^2)/2)*(Par.sig_ax^2) 0 0 0; 
                     ((Par.sig_ax^2)*(Par.dt^3))/2 ((Par.sig_ax^2)*(Par.dt^2)) ((Par.sig_ax)^2)*Par.dt 0 0 0;
                     ((Par.dt^2)/2)*(Par.sig_ax^2)  ((Par.sig_ax)^2)*Par.dt    (Par.sig_ax)^2 0 0 0;
                      0 0 0 ((Par.sig_ay^2)*(Par.dt^4))/4 ((Par.sig_ay^2)*(Par.dt^3))/2 ((Par.dt^2)/2)*(Par.sig_ay^2);
                      0 0 0 ((Par.sig_ay^2)*(Par.dt^3))/2 ((Par.sig_ay^2)*(Par.dt^2)) ((Par.sig_ay)^2)*Par.dt;
                      0 0 0 ((Par.dt^2)/2)*(Par.sig_ay^2) ((Par.sig_ay)^2)*Par.dt  (Par.sig_ay)^2 ];  


end
```

Thank You[image]

Comment: Looks like your covariance tuning is not ideal. Please provide the code and a working example; than we don't have to guess =P

Comment: @max Hello max, I have written my code in MATLAB. Its a bit messy. Here we go.  Link to the codes:https://drive.google.com/open?id=18UNEBe7P8y6tzWcr0FjROOGYF5nu4bnW. In that MOT is the main code. And the rest are functions. And In the Track initialization, I have declared the R matrix and parameters function, I have initialized the Q matrix. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Why don't you just post the code here? That is actually what this platform is for ;) -- create a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it so that other can reproduce your problem. Ideally, you'll get an example that works as you wished for back

Comment: @max I have placed my code it the updated question. Can you please check for the error?

Comment: @max. My thought exactly. Implementing a Kalman filter is relatively easy. Tuning it is hard. Careers are made on the latter task.

Comment: @MadPhysicist So, can you guide me how to tune the Kalman filter?